# How to insert default data into an Ecto database?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a table which contains the job types that can be created, and a migration and schema to go with these, however I would like to insert default data into the table on migration / creation.

Currently, I resort to just adding the data myself and hoping I don't accidentally rollback too far, but I would like a more robust solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called "seeds".

In your `mix.exs`, create an alias like this:

```
  defp aliases do
    [
      "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
```

Now just create that file `priv/repo/seeds.exs` and put something like this in it:

```
case Mix.env() do
  :dev ->
    IO.puts("Let's add some data!")
    {:ok, job_0} = YourModule.create_job(%{name: "job_0"})
    {:ok, job_1} = YourModule.create_job(%{name: "job_1"})

  _ ->
    nil
end
```

Note that I am careful to only run "seeds" in the `:dev` environment.

With all this setup, you can just do `mix ecto.drop` to drop the current database and then `mix ecto.setup` to create a new database, run migrations and populate with seed data.

What I have written is purely illustrative. You are free to make any kind of mix alias and seeds script you want.

Comment: Thanks! As for 'jobs', how would I go about actually adding an entry to a table? Is there somewhere to specify what the jobs do? I looked for documentation but couldn't find it in the Ecto docs "^^

Comment: "job" was just an example here, you call functions from your contexts, like e.g. `Account.User.create_user(attrs)`.